# Python module __builtin__ has no attribute NoneType

Tags: python

For reasons out of scope of this question, I'm building a serialization mechanism.  I've run into a problem with `None` objects that I think I need to special case.  Can anybody explain why `NoneType` is treated differently from other builtin types?  Or am I missing something?

```
>>> import sys
>>> builtin = sys.modules['__builtin__']
>>> getattr(builtin,'int')
<type 'int'>
>>> getattr(builtin,'list')
<type 'list'>
>>> getattr(builtin,'NoneType')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NoneType'
```

python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu

#### Clarification

Of course

```
getattr(builtin,'None')
```

works and returns a `None` object, which is an instance of `NoneType`.  But the class object exists in the `__builtin__` module for everything else.  So this code works for every built in type except `None`:

```
klass = getattr(builtin, obj.__class__.__name__)
```

which makes sense given that

```
>>> type(0).__module__
'__builtin__'
>>> type("foo").__module__
'__builtin__'
>>> type(None).__module__
'__builtin__'
```

The fact that this fails for `None` seems like an oversight in Python, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: `getattr(builtin,"None")`  ... maybe ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is odd.  But so are plenty of odd things about classes and objects in python 2.  This is true of a bunch of languages that evolved from simple scripts to full-fledged OO.  Python 3 is intended to solve this.

NoneType is a special case already because it is the class object for a singleton, so it can't be called as a constructor.

```
TypeError: cannot create 'NoneType' instances
```

So, if you are writing a general serializer then you will need to special case None anyway, irregardless of whether you can't look up the class object.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose what you call `NoneType` is treated specially because you hardly never need to access it. You could say

```
>>> NoneType = type(None)
```

to bind this type to a name, but that would serve no common purpose: `isinstance(x, NoneType)` would be a contrived equivalent to `x is None`; the constructor raises a `TypeError` stating that you're not supposed to construct instances; and deriving from it is forbidden too.

You can still get to the type via either `type(None)`, `None.__class__`, or `types.NoneType`, though, if you need it for some advanced purpose.

Answer (score 1):

NoneType is available in the types module.

```
>>> import types
>>> types.NoneType
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Infact types module is the right place to use if you are doing anything with types, don't rely on types being present in the **builtins**

It is probably to do something with the fact that None is not really a type, it s a [builtin constant](http://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html). Even the docs say the type of None is types.NoneType,  but you are right it is implemented in a special manner and is inconsistent from all other types.

Comment: Clearly I can't rely on it because it's not there.  But its omission makes no sense considering everything else is there.

Comment: @Leopd: of course it makes sense; why should there be a builtin for a constructor to make a singleton that's already builtin?

Comment: i get AttributeError: module 'types' has no attribute 'NoneType'

Comment: It's only available from python3.10 https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.NoneType

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at:

```
>>> dir(builtin)
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', 'AttributeError', 'BaseException', 'BufferError', 'BytesWarning', 'DeprecationWarning', 'EOFError', 'Ellipsis', 'EnvironmentError', 'Exception', 'False', 'FloatingPointError', 'FutureWarning', 'GeneratorExit', 'IOError', 'ImportError', 'ImportWarning', 'IndentationError', 'IndexError', 'KeyError', 'KeyboardInterrupt', 'LookupError', 'MemoryError', 'NameError', 'None', 'NotImplemented', 'NotImplementedError', 'OSError', 'OverflowError', 'PendingDeprecationWarning', 'ReferenceError', 'RuntimeError', 'RuntimeWarning', 'StandardError', 'StopIteration', 'SyntaxError', 'SyntaxWarning', 'SystemError', 'SystemExit', 'TabError', 'True', 'TypeError', 'UnboundLocalError', 'UnicodeDecodeError', 'UnicodeEncodeError', 'UnicodeError', 'UnicodeTranslateError', 'UnicodeWarning', 'UserWarning', 'ValueError', 'Warning', 'ZeroDivisionError', '_', '__debug__', '__doc__', '__import__', '__name__', '__package__', 'abs', 'all', 'any', 'apply', 'basestring', 'bin', 'bool', 'buffer', 'bytearray', 'bytes', 'callable', 'chr', 'classmethod', 'cmp', 'coerce', 'compile', 'complex', 'copyright', 'credits', 'delattr', 'dict', 'dir', 'divmod', 'enumerate', 'eval', 'execfile', 'exit', 'file', 'filter', 'float', 'format', 'frozenset', 'getattr', 'globals', 'hasattr', 'hash', 'help', 'hex', 'id', 'input', 'int', 'intern', 'isinstance', 'issubclass', 'iter', 'len', 'license', 'list', 'locals', 'long', 'map', 'max', 'memoryview', 'min', 'next', 'object', 'oct', 'open', 'ord', 'pow', 'print', 'property', 'quit', 'range', 'raw_input', 'reduce', 'reload', 'repr', 'reversed', 'round', 'set', 'setattr', 'slice', 'sorted', 'staticmethod', 'str', 'sum', 'super', 'tuple', 'type', 'unichr', 'unicode', 'vars', 'xrange', 'zip']
```

`NoneType` is not listed as a builtin type (even though `None` is)

Answer (score 0):

you should try :  `getattr(builtin,"None")` not `getattr(builtin,"NoneType")`, as `NoneType` is the value of `type(None)`, so it's not an attribute of `builtin`.

```
In [49]: type(None)

Out[49]: <type 'NoneType'>
```

this doesn't works, as Python is not able to find out `NoneType` anywhere.

```
In [50]: type(NoneType)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/monty/<ipython console> in <module>()
NameError: name 'NoneType' is not defined
```